# Can I repair a broken cubic/patterned breeze block with plaster or something similar?

Tags: repair, brick, cement

At my place there is a feature wall with those patterened cubic breeze blocks. A couple of them are broken (eg some of the "spokes" are missing).

Is it possible to repair these with some kind of plaster or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. I guarantee all cement and mortar to get hard and crack. The problem with such products is that it is wet when installed. As the water evaporates, the product physically shrinks.

Blue bolts or nails in gently drilled holes can be used to pin the new to the old. Then, when the new cracks as it dries, the pieces will stay in place. Wires can be used from pin to pin to assist in construction and keep the pieces in place if they crack in the middle.

Therefore, I suppose anything is possible if you try hard enough. But it would much easier to remove the entire block and replace it with a new one. It would be even easier to grind the broken smooth so that it looks like it is not supposed to have a web, then insert a trinket of your liking.

Comment: Good idea with the trinket